# Stop syncronsing the contacts

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

I have bought moto g4 and I has the problem that even though I delete the contacts the are updated after some time

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 - In your phone settings, visit the 'Accounts' section and disable syncing of contacts with the account(s) linked to your phone. Most probably Google accounts.

Option 2 - If that doesn't work, then when in your phone's address book, go to the settings and select which contacts you want to show in the address book.